# Where is the source of the Seneca quote “to be good, it is not enough to be better than the worst”?

Tags: reference-request, quote

Where Seneca says something like:

> To be good, it is not enough to be better than the worst.

I am looking for the correct preferably online reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Bonitas non est pessimis esse meliorem.

translated as "goodness does not mean merely being better than the lowest"

in  [Epistles vol.2 LXXIX](http://www.stoics.com/seneca_epistles_book_2.html#%E2%80%98LXXIX1) (Number 89, "On the rewards of scientific discovery"), Translated by Richard M. Gummere. The Loeb Classical Library. Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard UP, 1917-25.

Comment: @Sasan The prompted link (LXXIX) is correct, but the link has been incorrectly programmed as (LXXXIX).

Comment: Ep2-207 something wrong with the links, sorry

Comment: @Sasan: The link has now been fixed, and the quoted sentence is easy to find there.  I’m sure you didn’t intend it, but suggesting sand1 should remove this answer comes across as a bit rude, since even without the fixed link, the text was a complete and correct answer to your question.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I didn’t mean to be rude. If the link was not correct, then the answer was not useful. But now that I checked and saw that the link is correct, I deleted my comment.

Comment: @sand1 What is the name of the specific epistle? Could you please add that to your answer too?

Comment: @Sasan I do not quite understand your request. The answer already says (and did from the first draft) that it is in epistle 89 (LXXIX in Roman notation is the number 89). In the link, it is under the pagination <Ep2-207>.